# Creating a new project in React Native

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, windows, react-native

Please I'm trying to create a new project in React Native but I can't start the project after creating it ? Can I anyone help me out. Thanks

Comment: in the official documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup, you can read how to create a project using the command npx react-native init yourNameProject and start your project using npm run start and npm react-native run-android. and if you are using yarn, you can use yarn start and yarn android.

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm start` by navigating into the react folder, the browser will automatically open localhost window.